# MongoDB $or query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I run following query in mongo shell:

```
db.Profiles.find ( { $or : [ { "name" : "gary" }, {"name":"rob} ] } )
```

It just returns nothing as expected(JSON)?

Comment: I have reverted that edit, it is not helpful to edit one of the OPs original problems out of the question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Use $in

For the query in the question, it's more appropriate to use [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#_S_in)

```
db.Profiles.find ( { "name" : { $in: ["gary", "rob"] } } );
```

### Why doesn't it work

There's a missing quote - the cli is waiting for you to finish the second part of your or:

```
db.Profiles.find ( { $or : [ { "name" : "gary" }, {"name":"rob} ] } )
..............................................................^
```

You need to finish the query sufficiently for the cli to parse it for it to then say there's a syntax error.

### Case insensitive matching

As indicated by a comment, if you want to search in a case insensitive manner, then you either use `$or` with a [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/):

```
db.Profiles.find ( { $or : [ { "name" : /^gary/i }, {"name": /^rob/i } ] } )
```

Or, you simply use one regex:

```
db.Profiles.find ( { "name" : /^(gary|rob)/i } )
```

However, a regex query that doesn't start with a fixed string cannot use an index (it cannot use an index and effectively do "start here until no match found then bail") and therefore is sub-optimal. If this is your requirement, it's a better idea to store a normalized name field (e.g. `name_lc` - lower case name) and query on that:

```
db.Profiles.find ( { "name_lc" : { $in: ["gary", "rob"] } } );
```

Comment: Wow, bad mistake. Thanks @AD7six

Comment: Your suggested query works much better.

Do I need to change any syntax if say names were capitalised in an array?

e.g.

name:["Gary", "rob"]

Comment: db.Profiles.find ( { "names" : { $in: [/gary/i, /rob/i] } } )

answered my own question I think.

Comment: @Fruitful will work - be wary of relying on queries that cannot be indexed - use [ensureIndex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex) appropriately and [profile](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/profile/) the db to identify slow queries (or use [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on individual queries). Otherwise with time things just get slow or stop being viable.