# How can I ignore a missing "." and still return the matching substring?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongoose

I have a scenario where peoples names like `John J. Doe` and `John J Doe` exist in two seperate databases

Using values from the first database I need to query my second database for an either or scenario and still return a match

```
[
  { _id: ..., name: 'John J Doe' },
  { _id: ..., name: 'John J. Doe' },
  { _id: ..., name: 'John J Doe' }
]
```

What can I do to query and get all results?

currently I am doing this:

```
const name = 'John J Doe'
records = db.getCollection('job_status_containers').find({ name: /^${name}/i })
```

an `$or` query is not an option, this is going to be coming in from an API request and it just needs to be able to find it without much fluff

```
GET /some_endpoint?name=${encodeURIComponent(name)}
```

Comment: `^John J\.? Doe$` - This might help.Refer to demo link https://regex101.com/r/3dhkVc/1 .

Comment: It’ll be more efficient if you can add a field normalising the names so you can do a simple search on that instead, if it’s an option. Not sure if still relevant today, but [here’s a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535022/761202).

Answer (score 1):

Hacky, but I did the following and it functionally works

##### docs with a `.`

```
const name = 'John J. Doe'
const records = db.getCollection('job_status_containers').find({ name: /^${name}/i })

console.log(records.length)
// 159
```

##### docs without a `.`

```
const name = 'John J Doe'
const records = db.getCollection('job_status_containers').find({ name: /^${name}/i })

console.log(records.length)
// 72
```

##### querying for both

- get rid of all `.`
- replace all spaces with a regex `.?`  that makes the `.` optional, and since the `.` can appear in unpredictable places in peoples names - just add after every word

```
const name = 'John J. Doe'.replaceAll('.', '').replaceAll(' ', '[.]? ') + '[.]?'
const records = db.getCollection('job_status_containers').find({ name: /^${name}/i })

console.log(records.length)
// 231
```

Comment: i think you are correct, `/John J[.]? Doe/g` would be the correct pattern, hadnt tested `John Jx Doe`

Comment: `/John J\.? Doe/g` is arguably more semantic, but functions the same.